# geoserver - WFS Error : bbox and cql_filter both specified but are mutually exclusive

Tags: c#, jquery, geoserver

I am trying to get the following WFS GET request to work:

http://domain.com:8080/geoserver/bla/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=testing&outputFormat=json&bbox=-120.67383749999999,26.667051210679244,-70.75196249999999,46.25581231694961

But when I add a cql_filter with the bbox filter I then get this error:

```
Error:bbox and cql_filter both specified but are mutually exclusive
```

http://domain.com:8080/geoserver/bla/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=testing&outputFormat=json&bbox=-120.67383749999999,26.667051210679244,-70.75196249999999,46.25581231694961&cql_filter=RENEWABLE='Biomass'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, the WFS specification says that the various shorthand filter KVPs are mutually exclusive, cannot be used in conjuction.

The good news is that you can encode the whole filter can be expressed as a single CQL_FILTER expression, see some docs here:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html#geometric-filters

As an alternative, you can also do the same using the FILTER parameter and using the XML OGC Filter encoding.

Comment: Thanks,I have also use below code,but getting solution @Andrea Aime

Comment: http://domain.com:8080/geoserver/bla/ows?
SERVICE=WFS&
VERSION=2.0.0&
REQUEST=GetFeature&
TYPENAMES=BaseMaps%3testing&
FILTER=(<Filter><Within><PropertyName>RENEWABLE/Biomass
<PropertyName><gml:Envelope><gml:lowerCorner>26.6670 -79.5797</gml:lowerCorner>
<gml:upperCorner>26.6670 -79.5797</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope>
</Within></Filter>)(<Filter><Within><PropertyName>
NAME_CAP/61.5<PropertyName><gml:Envelope><gml:lowerCorner>46.2558 -70.75196
</gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>43.8219 -79.2693</gml:upperCorner>
</gml:Envelope></Within></Filter>)

Comment: Yes, that's another way, using a FILTER XML instead (same as  using the CQL_FILTER, different syntax). I'll update the answer